# "... that had stopped half an hour ago" VS " ... that had stopped half an hour before/earlier"

Tags: word-choice

This is a sentence I read:

> The engines that had stopped half an hour *ago* were in action again.

In my opinion, *ago* in the above sentence is used incorrectly. It should be replaced by before or earlier:

> The engines that had stopped half an hour *before* were in action again.
>   The engines that had stopped half an hour *earlier* were in action again.

I think ago can only used in the past tense rather than past perfect tense. 
Here is a correct sentence, making the correct use of *ago* as follows:

> The engines that stopped half an hour *ago* are in action again.

Is this thinking correct?

Comment: http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv350.shtml

Comment: I find "ago" to be "uncomfortable" in such scenarios.  I'd likely use "earlier".

Comment: @HotLicks depends on the context.  In the narrative of a novel, it can heighten the reader's sense of connection to the protagonist, helping them share the character's experience rather than just read a report of it.

Comment: @itsbruce - Yeah, in fiction the writer's "voice" is important, and often will outweigh issues of clarity or smoothness of word flow.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are in error.  "Ago" means "counting back from now", but in a narrative, *now* is the time being described.  So

> He went back to the engine room.  The engines that had stopped half an hour ago were in action again.

is just valid as

> I go back to the engine room.  The engines that stopped half an hour ago are in action again.

In both cases, "ago" is accurately describing the relative interval between the current *narrative* time and the previous time.  "In the past" relative to the contextual time.

Answer (score 1):

How come you have the opinion that "ago"  can't be used with past perfect tense?

See Collins dictionary ago. They have examples with past perfect + ago.

http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ago

The example from Collins is not the best as it is indirect speech.
Better examples from http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/ago

Only a few minutes ago she had flaunted death.

Long ago she had learned to ignore the second glances, open stares, and sometimes even suggestive leers of men.

Answer (score 1):

[Ago](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/before-and-ago/) – at a certain time before, counting back from the present

> The engines that had stopped half an hour ago (implying at a certain time -half an hour- before) were in action again.

[Before](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/before-and-ago/) – at some unknown time before now.

> The engines that had stopped before (unknown time) were in action again.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with both itsbruce and rogermue, and would like to add something more.

Using before in such a context, seems to be a bit "unfluent", since there is no mention about which event, "before" refers to. It should be along the lines of:

> The engines that had stopped half an hour **before *(event)*** were in action again.

Answer (score 0):

> “half an hour ago” VS “half an hour before”
>
> - half an hour ago = half an hour before NOW.
> - half an hour ago = half an hour before THEN (before a past time)

A reference from **Michael Swan's Oxford Basic English usage** (p29) :

[image: Oxford English Usage]